# When using BING SEARCH API, how do you omit duplicate results?

Tags: python, duplicates, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I built a python 2.7 BING SEARCH API pull, that returns 50 counts per page, and paginates by changing the offset value by a value of 50 each time. My results are written to a JSON file.

I am specifying a User-Agent and X-Search-ClientIP in the header of my api call. I am also specifying a responseFilter of webpages, as well as the mkt value of 'en-us'.

I am concerned, because I'm getting several duplicate search results. When I page 10 times (thus, retrieving 50 X 10 = 500 results), roughly 17% of these are duplicate records. Is there a way that I can force bing to only return non-duplicate values? What extra steps do you recommend I take, to get as close to getting back unique values only?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import httplib, urllib, base64, json, re, os, sys, codecs, locale, time

pull_count = 50                            ## Var used to control # of hits per pull
offset = 0                                 ## Var used to push pagination counter to http get
num_paginations = 10                       ## Var used to control max # of paginations
local_counter = 1                          ## Helps Write commas to json file for all but last run
timer_counter = 1                          ## Variable used to make system wait after 5 pulls
dump_file = 'BingDump.json'                ## Name of local file where results are written to
api_domain = 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
query = 'Bill Gates'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (MAC OSX, Educational Usage Only)'
x_search = '199.99.99.99'

#Request Headers, open connection, open file write to output file
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MYSUBSCRIPTIONKEY',
    'User-Agent' : user_agent,
    'X-Search-ClientIP': x_search,
}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(api_domain)
fhand = open(dump_file,'w')

#Function to build URL for API PULL
def scraper() : 
    pull_count_str = str(pull_count)
    offset_str = str(offset)
    params = urllib.urlencode({
        'q': query,
        'count': pull_count_str,
        'offset': offset_str,
        'mkt': 'en-us',
        'safesearch': 'Moderate',
        'responseFilter': 'webpages', #controls whether pull scrapes from web/image/news etc
    })
    return(params)

#Function set to wait 4 seconds after 5 pulls
def holdup(entry) : 
    if entry != 5 : 
        entry += 1
    else: 
        entry = 1
        time.sleep(4)
    return(entry)

#Function that establishes http get, and writes data to json file
def getwrite(entry1, entry2) : 
    conn.request("GET", "/bing/v5.0/search?%s" % entry1, "{body}", entry2)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    fhand.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)) 

#Main Code - Pulls data iteratively and writes it to json file
fhand.write('{') 

for i in range(num_paginations) : 

    dict_load = '"' + str(local_counter) + '"' +  ' : '
    fhand.write(dict_load)
    try:
        link_params = scraper()    
        print('Retrieving: ' + api_domain + '/bing/v5.0/search?' + link_params)
        getwrite(link_params, headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
        fhand.write('"Error. Could not pull data"')        
    offset += pull_count
    if local_counter != num_paginations : fhand.write(', ') 
    local_counter += 1
    timer_counter = holdup(timer_counter)

fhand.write('}')
fhand.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Wanted to ask BING API experts if including MSEDGE details into my header parameters will improve the quality of the returned search results, and if there's anything else that can be done that will yield results with less duplicates. I did a pull which involved 10,000 search results, of which roughly 900/10,000 or so were unique (less than 10%). Some search results were repeated as many as 800 times.

Comment: I can concur, I have the same problem. As I get more and more pages there are more and more dupes, but still from time to time there are new items.  I'm wasting a lot of api calls getting duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inquiry. We noticed you have the following # of paginations:

One thing I noticed is that the pagination is set to 10.

```py
num_paginations = 10 ## Var used to control max # of paginations.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using num_paginations to define the number of times to perform HTTP REQUESTS against Bing. So If I want to perform 10 requests, I will set that var to 10. I use 'pull_count' to set the # of search results I want (which is 50) PER request. The URL my code produces has a different offset # per http request.

My request URLs all have &count = 50. For the first request URL, I use &offset=0, then &offset = 50, then &offset=100. etc. Theoretically from everything I've read on documentations/forums, I should be good to go. Is there anything else you recommend I do?